# Accordion / multiple instances - only one opened

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

i am using ui accordion.

i have multiple instances of the same accordion on one page.

because it is the same accordion duplicated,
the links inside it have the same href value,
so every accordion is opened...
but I need only one OPENED accordion, the one were the click came from.

Is this possible?
Can someone help me with this?

thank u.

```
$('#nav ul li').accordion({ 
        active: 'a.current',
        header: '.head', 
        navigation: true, 
        event: 'click', 
        //fillSpace: true, 
        animated: 'easeslide',
        collapsible: true,
        autoHeight: false
    });




      $("#nav ul li").each(function () {
        var li = $(this);
        var a = li[0].firstChild;
        if (a.href == location.href) {
            $(a).addClass("current");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement a (this) into your jquery code, can you post your current code so we can see

The only thing i can think of is this:

```
$('#nav ul li', this).accordion({ 
    active: 'a.current',
    header: '.head', 
    navigation: true, 
    event: 'click', 
    //fillSpace: true, 
    animated: 'easeslide',
    collapsible: true,
    autoHeight: false
});
```

Comment: yeah you cant post code in the comments section. Edit your original answer and put in backticks

Comment: if you take the code above in your comment and go to your original question and press edit, then click on the code button then paste it between the two ``

Comment: thank u benhowdle89. i found another solution. I'll change the href.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try something like this:

```
$(".ac-menu").accordion({
    "header": "a.menuitem"
})
.bind("accordionchangestart", function(e, data)
{
    data.newHeader.next().andSelf().addClass("current");
    data.oldHeader.next().andSelf().removeClass("current");
})
.find("a.menuitem:first").addClass("current")
.next().addClass("current");
```